# Height and actual height returning zero in converter

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an items control and placed a panel in the items panel of Items Control. I want to set the height of my panel using the converter, so in this converter I need to access the height property of Items control but it returns 0.0.

Actually requirement is, I need to arrange objects in a particular order in ArrangeOverride method of panel, on the basis of panels height, so I need to know the height or width panel will be getting, in ArrangeOverride Method.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CircleGrid"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <ItemsControl Name="CircleNavigatorItemsControl"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                            Path=DataContext.DocumentsItemsSource}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <controls:CircularLayoutPanel x:Name="CircularPanel"  >
                                        <controls:CircularLayoutPanel.InnerRadius>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CircleNavigatorWidthConverter}" ConverterParameter="True">
                                                <Binding  Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="CircleNavigatorItemsControl" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

You *shouldn't* need to do this and I would advise against it. If your `Panel` is not getting sized correctly by the `ItemsControl` automatically, then I can only assume that your logic inside the `Panel.MeasureOverride` and/or `Panel.ArrangeOverride` methods has one or more errors.

Comment: ok may be I have't provided the complete info, I need to arrange objects in a particular order in ArrangeOverride method of panel, on the basis of panels height, so I need to know the height or width panel will be getting, in ArrangeOverride Method.

Comment: Can't you just use the `Size` input parameter from the `ArrangeOverride` method... that is usually how this is achieved.